# Question regarding the Guna based classification of Kalpas and the devatas therein

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, gunas, kalpa

According to certain Puranas, Kalpas are divided into three categories. In Sattvika kalpas, the greatness of Vishnu is predominant, In Rajasika Kalpas the greatness of Brahmā is predominant and in Tamasika Kalpas the Greatness of Shiva is predominant.

Does this mean liberation can only be attained by worshipping the deity whose greatness is predominant in the said Kalpa? As an example, would worshipping Shiva in Sattvika kalpas or Brahmā in Tamasika kalpas lead to liberation or not?